# Consul Server node vs client node

Tags: docker, service, cluster-computing, consul

In a consul cluster, I have few servers and few clients. Each client node is primarily a VM that hosts bunch of docker containers and each docker container is registered as service in the node/catalog.

My question is, like client node, can (or should) server node also have docker containers registered as services ?  or is it only consul clients who are supposed to host and provide services ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't matter, just monitor how much resources the consul server needs for your load. Start with a dedicated consul server and once you figured out the spare resources use them for your container services.

Looking at the performance requirements https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/performance.html indicating cpu intensive work, a dedicated consul only server would probably be recommended

Comment: Thanks Gert. Technically it will work .. but in general, from Consul perspective, what is the suggested approach -  Consul server can also host services, or should it be dedicated for consul server operations.

Comment: added a link above